# React - Error: Could not find required file; Searched in ../../public

Tags: reactjs, webpack, mern

I'm making a MERN app and get the above error after running `npm start`. I removed the `index.html` and `public folder`, then replaced it with `client/index.ejs`. My `webpack.config.js` file looks like this:

```js
//webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
module.exports = {
 entry: './client/index.js',
 output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
  filename: 'bundle.js'
 },
 module: {
  loaders: [{
   test: /.jsx?$/,
   loader: 'babel-loader',
   exclude: /node_modules/,
   query: {
    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
   }
  },
  {
   test: /\.css$/,
   loader: "style-loader!css-loader"
  }]
 }
}
```

Also, this is my first post on StackOverflow. Woohoo!

Comment: Congrats on your first Stack Overflow post! Webpack needs the `index.html` file in order to do hot reloading. Does your `webpack.config.js` file reference `index.html`?

Comment: My ```webpack.config.js``` file is looking for an entry at ```.client/index.js.``` It's looking for the /public folder, but it isn't there anymore. Hmm.

Comment: What is `npm start` in your `package.json` file? It may be helpful to post that as well.

Comment: ```npm start``` is ```"start": "react-scripts start";```